# Why is setmaxage not allowing longer time than ~5mins

Tags: java, jsp, cookies

In my jsp file I am setting a cookie I want to persist for a year. I have used the set max age and multiplied my seconds so it is a year. However the cookie only lasts for around 5mins. Even if I put in a ridiculously large value it still only lasts for ~5mins.

I am testing on localhost could that have anything to do with it?

Code below:

```
    //value to check if the EU compliance cookie is present
boolean euCookiePresent = false;
//cookie parameters
String cookieName = "wtr_ca";
String cookieValue = "1";
int cookieExpiry = 365;

//cookie expiary is in seconds so convert to days
cookieExpiry = cookieExpiry * 60 * 60 * 24;

//Get clients cookies
Cookie cookies [] = request.getCookies ();

if (cookies != null){
    //iterate over users cookies to check for euCookie
    for (int i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) 
    {
        if (cookies [i].getName().equals (cookieName)){
            euCookiePresent = true;
            break;
        }
    }

}

if (euCookiePresent == false){
    //no EU Cookie found therefore place it on client
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    Cookie cookie = new Cookie(cookieName,cookieValue);

    //cookie expiary is in seconds so convert to days
    cookie.setMaxAge(cookieExpiry);
    response.addCookie(cookie); 
}
```

Comment: `//cookie expiary is in seconds so convert to days` It is actually the other way arround: `//cookie expiary is in seconds so convert from days to seconds`. The conversion itself is fine though. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason Maven was no longer placing my new code on the server so it was still using my 365 seconds and not the updated code which converted it to days.

Comment: So your code above is working? If so, I would suggest deleting this question, as it is not valid.

Comment: I tried but as it has already been answered I am unable to delete.

Comment: I see. I flagged it to get moderator attention, so they can delete the question. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
cookie.setMaxAge(60*60*24);
```

sets the max age to about 1 hour, no a year

what you are trying to do is:

```
cookie.setMaxAge(cookieExpiry);
```

Comment: Sorry that was for testing, even when I specified that value above it still only remained for ~5mins